# Understanding EU blue-card and related rules

Tags: eu, blue-card

## #

Facts :

- Blue card minimum salary requirement 53600 (2019)
- If it is less then 53600 and more then 40800, then must fall into specific prefession
- If one holds blue card, has a fixed salary, has required qualification (anabin) then he/she can apply for niederlassungerlaubnis after 21 months or 33 months
  (source: bamf.de)

Questions:

- Anyone having less then EURO 53600 is entitled for blue card ?
- If YES, Any one having blue card under this circumstance is entitled for niederlassungerlaubnis (German B1) or later 33 months ?
- why the matrix is skewed that profession like doctors, mathematicians are paid less then IT professionals etc.

Comment: Doesn’t the second bullet under ‘facts’ answer the first one under ‘questions’?

Comment: no, thats why the question. If the resource/job-seeker does not get the specified role (arts, nurse, teacher, mathematician, etc) and YET gets less salary, what does he get. Is it still a blue card (with some exception) ?

Comment: @IratelNWIT Then you need to amend the question to make it clearer, per your comment

Comment: Called bamf and got following reply: if salary more than 53600 then no priority review required by Arbeitsagentur, Else need to go through by Arbeitsagentur for determining ( priority review) if the role and job description falls under highly skilled and in-demand category. It is also gets checked if a non resident or resident is available in that area first in line matching the same requirements. Else a work permit is granted.